# Store telegram_send API keys on a linux machine and use in python while keeping them private?

Tags: python, bash, telegram

I have a bit of a headscratcher on my hands that I am not sure what to do with (or if it is even possible). I have written a script for batch runs of a program called ORCA (quantum chemistry calculation software). It runs on a PC that is available to the entire working group at my uni.

These calculations can take very long to execute and if would be nice if I could implement an optional function that lets people receive updates on telegram about the progress of their calculations and their results. So the general idea is as follows:

First, encrypt the Telegram API token using gpg. User sets their passphrase.

```bash
echo "TELEGRAM_TOKEN" | gpg --symmetric --armor --output tgt_USER_NAME.asc
```

Store the .asc files for all users in some common location, like

```bash
~/.asc/usrid1.asc
~/.asc/usrid2.asc
...
```

Call the optional commandline option -f (follow) from the `run_orca.sh` script:

```bash
./run_orca -f usrid
```

User is prompted to put in their private passphrase.
If condition is triggered, which runs a py-script with the `telegram_send` code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# defaults
folder="inpsfolder"
extension="inp"
follow="" 


while getopts "i:x:f:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    (i) folder="$OPTARG";;
    (x) extension="$OPTARG";;
    (f) follow="$OPTARG" ;; # user types in their id (something like jdoe)
  esac
done


token_path="~/.asc/${follow}"
token="$(gpg --decrypt ${token_path})"

if [ $follow!="" ]
then
    python /path/to/script.py -t "$token" # telegram_send code is run and sends updates to the user.
fi
```

Is this safe? The users should just be able to echo out their own telegram API token if they know their personal passphrase, right? Is this even a good idea?

Comment: You might be interested in [BashFAQ/069](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/069) here...as written you're exposing the token to anyone who knows to look at the process table (e.g. `ps`). You'd probably be safer giving the user id to the python script and letting it do the work of prompting the user for a passphrase and decrypting the secret internally.

Comment: I have read up on telegram-send for the command line as opposed to python scritpts. I just realised that I do not need to provide the token of my bot each time I send a message using `telegram-send` once I have authenticated it through the botfather. The problem is that this authentification is system-wide and it doesn't seem like I can add a flag to a telegram-send command that prompts the user for a passphrase each time. And even if that is possible (which I can't find out since the website rahielkasim.com seems to be defunct) that would probs still show up in `ps(1)`.